# How to add same rectangle 10 times in a Row

Tags: flutter

I already created one tiny rectangle, How do I display 10 such rectangles one after the other in a Row.

I expect 10 such rectangles one after the other in aRow fashion, But actually, it shows only one, I tried even adding canvas inside row.[`This is the output I got`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXo2L.png)

```
class YourdrawRect extends CustomPainter {
    @override
    void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
        canvas.drawRect(
          new Rect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 100.0),
          new Paint()..color = new Color(0xFF0099FF),
        );
        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0));

        canvas.drawRect(
          new Rect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 100.0),
          new Paint()..color = new Color(0xFF0099FE),
        );
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: you are calling `drawRect` with the same `Rect` parameters (`Rect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 100.0),`) - simply add, for example `10` to `left` and `right` parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use ListView.builder with Axis.horizontal

```
ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: CustomPaint(
                    painter: YourdrawRect(),
                  ),
                );
              })
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('text'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: Center(
            child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            // You can add 10 YourRect() here or use loop
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: (YourRect()),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: (YourRect()),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class YourRect extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawRect(
      new Rect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 100.0),
      new Paint()..color = new Color(0xFF0099FF),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(YourRect oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```